# How do I make a discord python command that stops another command?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I've been trying to make a repeat command that repeats a message a couple times but I'd like to make a command that makes it so that it stops the repeated text. I don't know how to make it stop, I tried to make it with different codes but they all really don't work so I'd probably be happy to know if someone can help me.

Comment: "I tried to make it with different codes but they all really don't work" - please show your attempts and explain how exactly they "don't work"

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using an [`asyncio.Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) to run a separately defined coroutine.
You'd have to assign the `Task` to a variable and use that to cancel it in the other command.

If you anticipate the command being run multiple times simultaneously, you could store a list of `Task`s and cancel each one in the other command.

Comment: What is the command to cancel the task, sorry im pretty new to discord bot making

Comment: Your question was how to make a command stop another command. You'd obviously need to make a separate command that stops the original command. You can name it whatever you want.